Typescript - wait for return before executing a function
I am trying to execute a function after the response is completed. How can I do that without setTimeout()?
I am uploading large files, if the file is small it is working fine, but if it is large the waiting time is not enaught.
 this.orderTestService.orderObservable$

.pipe(untilDestroyed(this))

.subscribe((response) => {    

  if(response){

    setTimeout( () => {

      this.service.getDocuments(); }, 1000 );

  }

 }

});


does getDocuments accept a callback parameter or return a promise?

You should subscribe to get the results whenever the call finishes.

I am subscribed, I added the whole code

I mentioned why in the question

You can use finalize operator, this operator executes your function when the observable completes.
this.orderTestService.orderObservable$
  .pipe(
    untilDestroyed(this),
    finalize(() => {
      this.service.getDocuments();
    })
  )
  .subscribe((response) => {
    if (response) {
      // Handle successful response 
    }
  });


Thank you. finalize shoud work, but how can I pass the response to finalize

try to create a closure around the response within the subscribe callback and access it from the finalize function:
this.orderTestService.orderObservable$
.pipe(
untilDestroyed(this),
tap(response => { // tap is optional for handling success response (if needed)
this.uploadResponse = response;
}),
finalize(() => {
if (this.uploadResponse) {
this.service.getDocuments(this.uploadResponse); // Pass the response
}
})
)
.subscribe((response) => {
// ... (original subscribe logic)
});
